# What are some verses that are dedicated to nirguna Brahman in the Upanishads?

Tags: upanishads, brahman

What are some verses that are dedicated to nirguna Brahman from the Upanishads?

Comment: Hopefully you will get answer here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38360/11875

Comment: @Just_Do_It thanks for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the few verses which prove Brahman as Nirguna from Upanishads

> He is bright, **formless**, all-pervading, existing without and
> within, unborn, without prana, without mind, pure and beyond the
> avyakrita, which is beyond all.(Mundaka Upanishad 2.1.2)
>
> Which is soundless, touchless, **formless**, undecaying, so tasteless,
> eternal and scentless, beginningless, endless, beyond the Mahat, and
> constant, knowing that, man escapes from the mouth of Death.(Katha
> Upanishad 1.3.15)
>
> That which is beyond this world, **is without form** and devoid of
> suffering. Those who know this become immortal. Others are drawn to
> suffering only.(Svetasvatara Upanishad 3.10)
>
> He is the unthinkable,  unmanifest,  of endless forms,  the good,  the
> peaceful,  Immortal,  the origin of the worlds,  without beginning,
> middle,  and end,  the only one,  all-pervading,  Consciousness,  and
> Bliss,  the **formless** and the wonderful.(Kaivalya Upanishad 6)
>
> This Brahman is birthless, free from sleep and dream, **without name
> and form**, ever-effulgent and omniscient. Nothing has to be done in
> any way with respect to Brahman. (Mandukya Karika 3.36)